# toilet intermittent runs

Tags: plumbing

I live in high rise condo with identical units on each floor.  Only when my neighbor directly above me flushes his toilet does my commode run briefly.  My toilet functions correctly.  Our building engineer has no answer for this.

Comment: Varying water pressure? What happens if you suddenly turn the bathroom faucets on or off?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal. Your "out pipe" and his share a connection. As the water rushes past your connection, suction is created, and a little water goes "out" your toilet. I would get one of those "refresh" kits that replace the flapper, just to be sure and call it done.

Comment: I agree that if the flapper is not sealing this could cause the problem with the vacuum created from a flush on a upper floor.

Comment: How is this possible? The flapper holds water in the tank.  If water suctioned it would be from the bowl.  Lowering the water in the bowl, can't cause suction at the flapper. Essentially the bowl overflows into try he drain. @EdBeal

Comment: @Tyson correct.

Comment: The water falling from above makes a negative pressure on the vent stack and pulls a little by the flapper, I have seen this in multi story buildings and a new flapper was all that was needed to fix it.

Comment: There's an air gap between the water in the bowl and the water in the tank.  I could see water being sucked from the bowl, but how could that create suction on the flapper? @EdBeal

Comment: There is a vent in the tank IE the over flow pipe the differential pressure created on a weak flapper pulls water by when it deforms. You would think the pressure would not be enough to cause this but I have replaced flappers and the problem went away. The first time I ran into this I had replaced the fill valve thinking it was the problem with a pressure drop. Changed the flapper out and it stopped. I have seen this  several times on houses as few as 3 story and water pressure in the 80psi range.

Answer (score 1):

Coteyr has the right idea, wrong pipe.  The water supply pipe is constricted somewhere below both your apartments. Probably from scale buildup.

His toilet's demand is causing a dramatic pressure drop, which is unseating your toilet's supply valve.  It's running a little bit, and you're hearing that.  It may be causing water to run out the tank overflow and into the bowl.

It may be exacerbated by difference in the toilet valves on the two units.

The bathroom faucets may not be on the same pipe, so maybe no help there.